# Punctual convergence of $f_n(x+1/n)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions (with real values) that converges uniformly to a continuous function $f$. I have to proof that $f_n(x+1/n)\to f(x)$ por each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

So I know that I have to prove punctual convergence but I have trouble understanding the problem since it is evaluated in $(x+1/n)$. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\left|f_n\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)\right|\leq \left|f_n\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right|+\left|f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)\right|$$
Now try to make the two terms on the right side small enough by taking large enough $n$.

Comment: hmm so each of those terms would be bound by $\frac{\epsilon]{2}$? where does the argument for the continous f enters ?

Comment: We need the continuity of $f$ to bound the second term and the uniform convergence for the first term.